# converting exponent value to normal

Tags: c#

i am using c# to read value of cells. One cell having a exponential value. When i am reading that value it is giving "F5" instead of that exponential value..

I am retriving cell value as:

```
 DataRow dr = dsSource.Tables[0].Rows[5];
            string text =(dr.Table.Columns[4].ToString());
```

and i am converting the value as:

```
double val = double .Parse(text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
```

but it is not converting. Any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a spreadsheet.  Column F, row 5.

Answer (score 1):

If Im not mistaken it looks like your retrieving the name of the column and not the value of the row.

Try this instead:

```
var value = (double)dsSource.Tables[0].Rows[5][4];
```